# MemoryCache's UpdateCallback is Broken, Only Works For Expired Items

Tags: c#, callback, memorycache

MemoryCache UpdateCallback seems to only fire for expired items.

Consider the following test code:

```
CacheItem cacheItem1 = new CacheItem("mykey", 1);
CacheItemPolicy policy1 = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy1.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(5);
policy1.UpdateCallback = new CacheEntryUpdateCallback(OnCacheItemUpdate);
MemoryCache.Default.Set(cacheItem1, policy1);

CacheItem cacheItem2 = new CacheItem("mykey", 2);
CacheItemPolicy policy2 = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy2.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(15);
policy2.UpdateCallback = new CacheEntryUpdateCallback(OnCacheItemUpdate);
MemoryCache.Default.Set(cacheItem2, policy2);

public void OnCacheItemUpdate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments args)
{
    // fires only for expired, but not for removed or replaced
}
```

Upon running this code **OnCacheItemUpdate** will fire only after the item expires after ~15 seconds, but not when its replaced from 1 -> 2.

This seems like a bug to me because CacheEntryUpdateArguments.RemovedReason can be other then Expired.  RemovedCallback behaves properly as expected.

Also the timing of expiration seems to be a bit delayed at times, its never exactly 15 seconds.

Is this a known bug or is somehow by design? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you are creating 2 independent CacheItem entries. Maybe there is some confusion on the "replaced from 1 -> 2". As for the expiration time it's not exact to when you have your expiration set. It's by design. I ran into it to. http://benhall.io/erratic-behaviour-from-net-memorycache-expiration/

Comment: @James - thanks for sharing the link. Regarding cache items, both have identical key, so one should replace the other. When using RemoveCallback that is the case.

Comment: wow I'm more tired than I thought. I could have sworn the two keys were different. Anyways, I was curious so I looked at the GitHub code. It looks like it's called when it's removed which as far as I can tell should happen when you replace (set with the same key). Maybe you can make more sense out of this. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Runtime.Caching/src/System/Runtime/Caching